# Manually changing attribute values for PostGIS layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, attribute-table

I am trying to edit the attributes of a PostGIS layer. I am able to create a new field using field calculator, but when I try to change a specific cell's value following [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values):

> typing the new value directly in the cell, whether the attribute table
>   is in table or form view. Changes are hence done cell by cell, feature
>   by feature;

, nothing happens when I type in the cell.

I've enabled the edit mode (and also tried the multi-edit) mode. This is with QGIS 3.0.1.

Are manual edits allowed for PostGIS layers or am I missing something?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure your PG user has all the necessary rights?

Comment: This sounds really trivial, but... have you pressed Enter when you've finished typing in the cell? If you type in the cell and then click elsewhere it won't register the change.